# Get how many customer for a city

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm currently strugling with an sql query i have to make, the aim is simple i have a table of customers and a table of purchases, it is linked via a foreign key in the purchase table.

the model is like that :
[the model in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgCki.png)

i guess i have to use the HAVING and COUNT functions in sql but i can't really figure out how to write the query correctly to have a result like that :

| CITY | Number_of_customer |
| --- | --- |
| Paris | 7 |
| London | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT C.CITY,COUNT(C.CUSTOMER_ID)CUSTOMER_COUNT
FROM CUSTOMER C
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM PURCHASE_ORDER AS RD 
      WHERE C.CUSTOMER_ID=RD.CUSTOMER_ID
)
AND C.CITY IN('Paris','London')-- not sure if it is necessary
 GROUP BY C.CITY
```

Comment: Is op only interested in paris and london I wonder

Comment: I agree with you it is possible. And it is also possible that he does not need to check PURCHASE_ORDER at all - just count people

Comment: @P.Salmon i'm not interested in those cities it was just an example but thanks for asking :)

Comment: @Sergey thank you for your answer i have now more vision on what i can do to achieve this. :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is # customers per city:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*) n_customers
FROM "CUSTOMER"
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY n_customers DESC
```

If you only want to count customers that have made at least one purchase:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(*) n_customers
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.city FROM "CUSTOMER" t1
    INNER JOIN "PURCHASE_ORDER" t2 ON t1.id = t2.customer_id
    GROUP BY t1.id
)
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY n_customers DESC;
```

Comment: Is op only interested in paris and london I wonder

Comment: thank you for your answer i have now more vision on what i can do.